# Protobuf: How to close GzipOutputStream on Windows?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use GzipOutputStream on windows, but while streaming out compressed seems to work, I can't close the file.

The way I'm trying it:

```
  int output_file_handle = -1;
  _sopen_s(&output_file_handle, accumulation_cache_file.c_str(),
           _O_CREAT | _O_BINARY | _O_TRUNC| _O_WRONLY | _O_SEQUENTIAL, _SH_DENYNO, 0);
  google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream zero_copy_out_stream(output_file_handle);
  google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream::Options compression_options;
  compression_options.compression_level = 1; // fastest
  google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream gzip_out_stream(&zero_copy_out_stream, compression_options);
  if(output_file_handle != -1) {
    for(int i=0...) {
      ...
      google::protobuf::util::SerializeDelimitedToZeroCopyStream(some_message_pointer, 
                                                                 &gzip_out_stream);
      if(i%10 == 0)
        gzip_out_stream.Flush();
    }
    gzip_out_stream.Close();
    //_close(output_file_handle);
  }
```

after that code runs through, the file is about 16MB (but I can't close  it so long as the app still runs, meaning it wasn't closed properly). When I end the application, the file size goes to about 250MB.
If I instead use the commented out _close(output_file_handle); then the app silently crashes at this point and the filesize is 250MB.

How to do this properly on windows with MSVC?

Comment: Call `zero_copy_out_stream.Close()` after `gzip_out_stream.Close()`

Comment: yep that did it, thank you :)